# Tableau: Time Between Fields

Tags: date, tableau-api, datediff

I have a data set simillar to the one pictured that I am using in Tableau. What I want to do is look at the amount of time an Opportunity spent in the Committed Stage before it went Closed Won.

My thought was to filter for only Opportunities that are currently Closed Won, and then filter for Opportunity Stage History of only Committed. Since Committed is usually the stage before Closed Won, I would calculate the difference between the Last Stage Change Date and the Closed Date. But that doesn't seem to be working.
Any thoughts are ver appreciated.